# R: Displaying text in plot as legend

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, gis

I have a map with 60 towns to be plotted.
I want to display the name of the towns but it is too cluttered. Is there a way I could number them and display the names as the legend like below?

[image: Required image]

I have tried "textxy" function from "calibrate" package but it displays only on the map.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the package **ggmap.** It allows you to get a base map and use ggplot functions to plot coordinates on top of the map. Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(ggmap)
library(dplyr)

# Get the base map
nevada <- get_map(location = 'nevada', maptype = "satellite", source = "google", zoom = 6)

# View the basemap
ggmap(nevada)

# Create data frame with cities and lat/long and an index
cities <- data.frame(city = c("Las Vegas", "Caliente", "Elko"), 
                 lat = c(36.169941, 37.614965, 40.832421), 
                 long = c(-115.13983, -114.511938, -115.763123))
cities <- cities %>% mutate(index = seq.int(nrow(cities)))

# Map with legend, colored by city
ggmap(nevada) + 
  geom_point(data = cities, aes(x = long, y = lat, color = paste(index, city)), cex = 3) +
  labs(color = "cities") +
  geom_text(data = cities, aes(x = long, y = lat, label = index), hjust = 2, color = "white")
```

[image: Map with legend, colored by city]

If you want all the cities to be colored the same, use `fill = city` instead of `color = city` and specify the color (e.g. `color = "red"`) outside of `aes()`.

```
# Map with legend, all cities same color
ggmap(nevada) + 
  geom_point(data = cities, aes(x = long, y = lat, fill = city), cex = 3, color = "red") +
  labs(fill = "cities") +
  geom_text(data = cities, aes(x = long, y = lat, label = index), hjust = 2, color = "white")
```

[image: Map with legend, cities same color]